# Resizing Button in a TableLayout, Dynamically (Android)

Tags: android, button, tablelayout, tablerow, layoutparams

Alright, I have searched for its solution But unable to find it. The Question is simple. There is a `TableLayout` in Android, I am adding few Rows in it. In the Last Row, I am adding a button. Now, the problem is the size of the button is not constant. What I mean is that, it fills the column. If the above data takes longer width of the column, the width of the button, accordingly increases. I have tried `LayoutParams`, `setHeight`, `setWidth` function too, but that didn't help me..

I would appreciate if someone would help me out.

```
TableLayout table=new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
Button button=new Button(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams trParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
Button.setLayoutParams(trParams); 
tableRow.AddView(button); 
table.addView(tableRow);
```

Comment: Share your xml file....

Comment: I am doing this dynamically i.e. programmitically.

Comment: TableLayout table=new TableLayout(this); TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this); Button button=new Button(this); TableRow.LayoutParams trParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); Button.setLayoutParams(trParams); tableRow.AddView(button); table.addView(tableRow);

Answer (score 0):

You have called setLayoutParams on Button not button.
Names are case sensitive. `Button` is the class while `button` is your object.
Try:

```
TableLayout table=new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
Button button=new Button(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams trParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
tableRow.AddView(button, trParams); 
table.addView(tableRow);
```

However this will not fix the main issue. According to the Reference docs all children of a TableRow are forced to MATCH_PARENT for their width.

You could try nesting your button inside another layout. For example put your button inside a horizontal LinearLayout, then put the LinearLayout into your TableRow.

Comment: TableLayout table=new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tableRow=new TableRow(this);
Button button=new Button(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams trParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button.setLayoutParams(trParams);
tableRow.AddView(button);
table.addView(tableRow);